# How to initialise a mongokitten server globally in a swift file other than the main.swift file?

Tags: swift, mongodb, mongokitten

I use mongodb to store all data of my mac application.So I use Mongokitten library as the interface between the db and my app. Inorder to connect to db initially and maintain the connection throughout the time when application is running I need to establish a one time connection to db. But I'm not able to initialise the server globally in the swift file.What i do is connect to the server each time a operation(insertion, updation, deletion, read) is performed.This causes the connection to the server to be lost once when these operations are executed over a limit and causes my application to hang. Can anyone please help me find a solution to make the server connection only once for throughout running of application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.Implicitly unwrap the server variable and assign value to server on checking server connection.
For reference follow the link :https://swiftmodules.com/planteam/mongokitten

Comment: https://github.com/openkitten/mongokitten is where our readme is located. The MongoKitten repository is not part of PlanTeam anymore, it is instead part of OpenKitten now. Any users of the link you posted will be running a *really* old version of MongoKitten (1.0). MongoKitten 4 has been out for quite a while now.